# Препод задал задачку на delphi, не могу понять что мне нужно с ней сделать

Tags: алгоритм, delphi-7

**Вычислить значение выражения при заданных значениях переменных X,Y**

```
     **X=true Y=true**
```

1. not (x and y) or (x or not y)
2. not y or (y or y and not x)
3. (y and y)   or (y or y or not x)
4. not x and (y or y and x) or y
5. not (not x and not y or not x) or y

Answer (score 3):

Просто Вам нужно вспомнить , что 
 1. Оператор **and** возвращает **true**, только если оба операнда - **true**, в противном случае - **false**;
 2. Оператор **or** возвращает **false**, только если оба операнда - **false**, в противном случае - **true**;
 3. Оператор **not** меняет булевскую переменную на противоположную;
 4. Скобки выполняются в первую очередь;
 Успехов!

Comment: Больше всего меня интересует в этом задании значение слова NOT

Comment: @Igor_bogun, так логическое НЕ же.

    NOT true = false
    NOT false = true

Comment: Всем огромное СПАСИБО

Answer (score 2):

> не могу понять что мне нужно с ней сделать

Так спросите у препода.

Варианта тут видится 2:

1. Надо просто эти выражения вычислить при помощи делфи. Задайте две переменные x=true и y=true. Ну и вычислите выражения. Они с точки зрения делфи синтакически корректны, можно прям так и использовать.
2. Надо вычислить их на бумаге, что логичнее с практической точки зрения.

Comment: Больше всего меня интересует в этом задании значение слова NOT